# how to embed a font for specific input text field using as3 codes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

how to embed a font for text1  which is an input text field   using as3 codes only

also in file text2 which is a dynamic text field how to get whole which I typed in text1

I appreciate everyone who would try to help me

this is my code

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;


stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, reportKeyDown);



function reportKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    stage.focus = text1;
 text2.text =(" Key Pressed:   " + String.fromCharCode(event.charCode) );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import flash.text.TextFormat;

var myForm:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myForm.font = new ArialRegular().fontName;
text1.setTextFormat(myForm);
```

"ArialRegular" is the declared class name of the embedded font.
To embed a font, select desired font from Family dropdown. Click the "Embed..." button, a dialog will appear. Give it a unique descriptive name and tic the checkboxes for the desired character ranges then select the "Actionscript" tab near the top of the dialog and then check the box next to "Export for Actionscript" under Linkage. The name you gave it on the previous tab will become the Class name. (ArialRegular for example)

As for duplicating the text from one to another, I haven't tested this and I'm kinda sleepy but should work:

```
text1.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, ditto);

function ditto(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    text2.text = ("Key Pressed: " + e.target.text);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks to you I implemented it but I noticed that when I started type the text from the second line the text not appear on the text2 also if I typed long text the same problem appears

Comment: I don't understand what problem you're having. What is the "second line"? Perhaps a screenshot would help?